# How to make a span tag do a line break if the text its too big?

Tags: html, css

```
 <li class="menuitem item ">
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/SupplierTenderCreate.php?New=Yes">

        <span>Create a New Tender</span>

    </a>
</li>
```

and that works fine however these are options in a side menu so sometimes the span tag that gives the option name has to much text and I want to make it so that it has a determinated width an if it surpases that width it puts a break line

I have tried with

```
.menuitem .item > a > span{
  display:block;
  width: 150px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

but it does not work also I know that it would be better to use divs but I cant change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your selector. Your list item has the two classes 'menuitem' and 'item'. If you want to match both of them, change the selector to `.menuitem.item > a > span`, effectively removing the space between. So try

```
.menuitem.item > a > span {
  display:block;
  width: 150px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the same parent twice:

`.menuitem` is the same element as `.item`

Try this:

```
.menuitem > a > span{}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5zc75th/)**

Answer (score 1):

give only `.item > a > span` for the selector

```css
.item > a > span{
  display:block;
  width: 150px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<li class="menuitem item ">
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/SupplierTenderCreate.php?New=Yes">

        <span>Create a New Tender</span>

    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code without touching your html.

```css
.menuitem.item a span {  width: 150px; display: block; }
```

```html
 <li class="menuitem item">
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/SupplierTenderCreate.php?New=Yes">

        <span>Create a New Tender and Create a New Tender and Create a New Tender and Create a New Tender</span>

    </a>
</li>
```